# How to concatenate multiple videos in ffmpeg JS using and Mute them as well in command line

Tags: ffmpeg

Using Command Line for FFMPEG in javascript to concatenate videos and muting them also. There was problem for me to find commands for JS in the following format

('-i', 'test.mp4', '-vf','reverse', 'out.mp4')

Comment: Are you looking for a solution in JS code?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a solution in JS npm cli then,

To concats a list of videos together is easy using ffmpeg package with transitions.

package on npm! `npm install ffmpeg-concat`

```
Usage: ffmpeg-concat [options] <videos...>
     
Options:
  -V, --version                         output the version number
  -o, --output <output>                 path to mp4 file to write (default: out.mp4)
  -t, --transition-name <name>          name of gl-transition to use (default: fade)
  -d, --transition-duration <duration>  duration of transition to use in ms (default: 500)
  -T, --transitions <file>              json file to load transitions from
  -f, --frame-format <format>           format to use for temp frame images (default: raw)
  -c, --concurrency <number>            number of videos to process in parallel (default: 4)
  -C, --no-cleanup-frames               disables cleaning up temp frame images
  -O, --temp-dir <dir>                  temporary working directory to store frame data
  -v, --verbose                         enable verbose logging from FFmpeg
  -h, --help                            output usage information
  
Example:
     
> ffmpeg-concat -t circleopen -d 750 -o huzzah.mp4 0.mp4 1.mp4 2.mp4
```

*Documentation:* https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg-concat

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ffmpeg.js the same arguments as FFmpeg would be passed to argument array

e.g for FFMPEG:

```
ffmpeg -i intro.mp4 -i video.mp4 -i outro.mkv \
       -filter_complex "[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a][2:v][2:a] 
                        concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]" \
       -map "[v]" -map "[a]" final.mp4
```

for FFmpeg.js its an optional approach to add the text files as commands and pass them into the `aurguments` array

as per the question if you want to mute the audio use the volume filter or add an empty audio with lowest duration e.g: 0.1 seconds.